# Where are previous closed questions or issues in Github

Tags: github, profile

In Github, I can view my current issues/question and participating questions from my profile page. However, previous resolved/closed issues seem are no longer there! There is no option to find them or filter them on the Github page?

How can I find/view my own **previous resolved issues/history questions** that are now closed, (they seem to disappear from my list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the search box on the [issues page](https://github.com/issues).

By default this contains something like `is:open is:issue author:<your-github-user>`. Change `is:open` to `is:closed` and hit enter.

When the search loads you can bookmark the URL for the search and come back any time.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what i was looking for. 1) Can I make this a feed I can subscribe to 2) is it possible to `maintain` *two* different, like `github` and `bitbucket` source code repositories on the same visual studio project?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and understanding my issue